# why does `ruby -v` return true in rails, rather than return the version?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This seems like a silly question, but it's got me stumped. If I do this in the rails console:

```
system('ruby -v')
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]
=> true
```

So it shows the version, but returns true. So I do this in an .erb file:

```
<%= system('ruby -v') %>
```

and it just prints "true" on the web page. I've searched google, though the words involved just make it harder since they are used in so many places I've found it hard to craft a query that will return what I want. Thus proving google is not an AI. :-)

Comment: If you're trying to get the version for the currently running ruby, you probably should use RUBY_VERSION rather than shelling out to another ruby process. Note that the ruby version accessible from the shell may not be the same as the ruby used to run the script if the ruby interpreter is not in the PATH.

Comment: Good point, I knew there had to be something in Rails that would reference the version it is running under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system` prints out the result of the command and returns whether it was a success or not. Try the `` syntax:

```
<%= `ruby -v` %>
```

Comment: D'OH! I started to try that one first and thought "hmmm, probably bad form, better use `system()`. LOL I didn't know the bit about it returning success, so learned something! Thanks. I'll accept as soon as it lets me (5 more minutes).

Answer (score 3):

[`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) executes the command and returns `true` if there was no error. So in this case the version is printed to the standard output and your program receives `true` which is included in your Erb output (check your log files, you might find the output of `ruby -v` in them.

What you probably want is `` ` `` (that’s a backtick). This is a [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60), but is called by using the backticks like quotes:

```
2.2.1 :001 > `ruby -v`
=> "ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin13]\n"
```

Note how this *returns* the output of the call to `ruby -v` rather than printing it.